# Is Ubuntu One Files available for iPad client?

Tags: ubuntu-one, ipad

I saw the post about there being Ubuntu One Files for the iPhone in the works, is there one for the iPad as well? This would be very helpful for my work.

Comment: You can run iPhone programs on iPad

Answer (score 1):

You can, if you point your browser to [here](https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/) and then follow the instructions.

PS: It is only Music the app will work for and it does have a monthly charge. Further information on the costs is [here](https://one.ubuntu.com/services/music/).

Update (06/01/2011): Canonical have released an iOS Ubuntu One Files app. It is available to download [here.](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ubuntu-one-files/id489935140?ls=1&mt=8)

Comment: I saw the one for music, was hoping the one for general files. Like how Android has both music and files. I have the Files client on my droid but a file client for the company ipad would be great...I would have gone with an Android tablet but that wasn't my decision to make.

Comment: Currently, the Ubuntu One app for iPhone and iPad are only music sharing.

Comment: Currently, the Ubuntu One app is for iPhone and iPad are only music.  
I'm not sure what there plans are for the future, but I would imagine they will look at files too.

Comment: Update: Ubuntu One Files app for iOS is now available to download from the Apple (App) store. Here's a link. http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ubuntu-one-files/id489935140?ls=1&mt=8